# No body-background-image with DOCTYPE

Tags: html, css, firefox, doctype

The body-Tag of a HTML-File does have a background-image applied:

```
body {… background: #fff url(./img/bg-body.jpg) no-repeat 0 82; …}
```

everything works just fine with WebKit (Safari, Chrome…) and even Trident (IE) … BUT the background-image is not showing in Gecko (Firefox) … and if I add the DOCTYPE to the document, it doesn't work anywhere.

```
<html>
    <head>
        <style type="text/css">
            body {… background: #fff url(./img/bg-body.jpg) no-repeat 0 82; …}
        </style>
    </head>
    <body>
        …
    </body>
</html>
```

It does also not work with no divs, no content, no nothing…

Any ideas?

Comment: Please show some more code. Also are you sure about the `.` in the URL?

Comment: yepp, the ./ is correct (it works fine in Safari, Chrome, IE).

Comment: Paths in CSS-files need to be relative to the CSS-file, are you absolutely sure your path is correct? What's `0 82` (background-position)? You need to specify a unit there.

Comment: yepp, the path is absolutely correct (as mentioned it works fine in Safari, Chrome and IE) … «./img/» means the same as «img/», so it's definitely the correct path to the background-image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to specify the unit for your background position

```
body{ background: #fff url(./img/bg-body.jpg) no-repeat 0 82px }
```

it seems to work in webkit without it. But gecko needs a unit. Then it should work.